# How to get the generic types used in a method in an array?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, types

I've got this generic method, and I want to make sure that the types specified are enums.
Now I understand I can't do something like `where T:enum`. But I want to make sure in runtime.

I know I could do it like `typeof(T).IsENum`. But I want to use reflection like so

```
public static List<Tuple<T, Y>> Produce<T, Y>()
    where T: struct, IConvertible
    where Y: struct, IConvertible
{
    var methodInfo = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
    foreach(var typeInMethod in methodInfo.GetGenericArguments()) 
        CheckTypeIsEnum(typeInMethod);
```

The problem is that the types returned by methodInfo.GetGenericArguments() aren't of the enum types I specified. But instead they are of type `T` and `Y` and `BaseType: {Name = "ValueType" FullName = "System.ValueType"}`.

Summarized: How do I get an array of all generic types used in the method?

P.S. .Net 4.5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should just use `typeof(T)` and `typeof(Y)` - those will give you the *actual* generic type arguments. There's no benefit to using reflection here: it's slow *and* gives you the wrong answers! As far as I'm aware, the generic type arguments simply aren't available with reflection at execution time. In particular, the method you're currently calling ([`MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getcurrentmethod.aspx)) explicitly documents that your approach will not work:

> If the currently executing method is a generic method, `GetCurrentMethod` returns the **generic method definition**.

(In other words, the version which doesn't have the type arguments specified - it only knows that you've got `T` and `Y`, but not what they are.)

So just get rid of your loop, and use:

```
CheckTypeIsEnum(typeof(T));
CheckTypeIsEnum(typeof(Y));
```

Also note that with a bit of IL hackery, you *can* have a constraint of `where T : enum`. It's not valid C#, but it's valid IL and the C# compiler obeys the constraint in IL it's looking at :) See my [Unconstrained Melody](https://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) project for an example.

Comment: I explicitly did not ask for `typeof(T)`. I want reflection, if possible. The project you link to seems interesting though.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk: *Why* don't you want `typeof(T)`? That gives you the right answer, whereas reflection simply doesn't... because when you get a generic method definition (which is what you'll get from `GetCurrentMethod`) there simply aren't any generic type arguments. Use the solution that works :)

Comment: @MikedeKlerk: I've added more information about why your current approach isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification. I just write the extra lines then for the function with 6 generic parameters. I thought I just couldn't find it. But you state it isn't possible. Seeing your technical C# background, I guess I have to look no further as it isn' possible (using C# in VS as is).

Comment: @MikedeKlerk: If you have this in multiple places, you could always write helper methods with variable numbers of type parameters which *just* validate them, e.g. call `ValidateEnums<T, Y>` or `ValidateEnums<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>`. That way at least it doesn't clutter up the code.